# Contents of stack after function call

Tags: c, assembly, gdb, stack, cpu-registers

I'm reading a book that explains how the `ebp` and `eip` registers work when a function is called. The following figure is provided:

[image]

here `array` is a local function variable. The function arguments are `a`, and `b`. This is how the actual C code looks like:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void function(int a, int b)
{
   int array[8];
}

int main()
{
   function(1,2);
   return 0;
}
```

I compile with `gcc -m32 -g function.c` and run the program in `gdb`. The command `disas main` shows (skipped some lines):

```
0x08048474 :    push   $0x2
0x08048476 :    push   $0x1
0x08048478 :    call   0x804843b 
0x0804847d :    add    $0x10,%esp
```

the first and last few instructions of function() are:

```
0x0804843b :    push   %ebp
0x0804843c :    mov    %esp,%ebp
0x0804843e :    sub    $0x38,%esp
0x08048441 :    mov    %gs:0x14,%eax
0x08048447 :    mov    %eax,-0xc(%ebp)
0x0804844a :    xor    %eax,%eax
0x0804844c :    nop
    ...
0x0804845e :    leave  
0x0804845f :    ret
```

and when I inspect the contents of `ebp`:

```
(gdb) x/4xw $ebp
0xffffcd48:     0xffffcd68      0x0804847d      0x00000001     0x00000002
```

I understand that in the stack, `ebp` should be followed by the return location `0x0804847d` and the function arguments `0x00000001` and `0x00000002`. However I don't know what is `0xffffcd68`. Is this the address of `ebp`?

Comment: Does your book describe what the EBP slot in the stack is?

Comment: Briefly: There is no stack in C. For your specific implementation, read the ABI, but keep in mind this is typically only for exported functions.

Comment: Can you show the first few instructions of `function`?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick the book has information about delay slots but I haven't read that section yet. I included the instructions of `function`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the value of `ebp` at the beginning of the function.
It's a consequence of `push %ebp` and the fact that the x86 stack is Full Descending.

It's the caller frame pointer.

---

Beware that the compilers update the way they handle the stack much more frequently than books authors do with their books.
Particularly: alignment, frame-pointer omission, RVO, implicit parameters and so on may throw you off.